# Nested async operations in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, promise

I am still quite new to writing code for Node.js (coming from PHP) and sometimes struggle to understand if async operations are working correctly, especially when there are multiple nested database calls/async operations.

For example, in this piece of code (which uses mongo), will the program only finish when `deleted` has been set on any required accounts? (see `todo` 1, 2 and 3):

```
// array of account emails to be compared against the accounts already in the database (using `email`)
var emailsArray; 

accountsDatabase.find({}, {})
    .then(function (accountsInDB) {
        return q.all(_.map(accountsInDB, function (dbAccount) {
            // compare account's email in db with emails array in memory using .email 
            if ((emailsArray.indexOf(dbAccount.email) > -1) === false) {

                // todo 1. should there be another 'then' here or is 'return' ok in order for it to work asynchronously?

                return accountsInDB.updateById(dbAccount._id, {$set: {deleted: true}}); 
            } else {

                // todo 2. is this return needed?

                return;
            }
        }));
    })
    .then(function () {

        // TODO 3. WILL THE PROGRAM POTENTIALLY REACH HERE BEFORE `deleted` HAS BEEN SET ON THE REQUIRED ACCOUNTS?

        callback(); // all of the above has finished
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        callback(err); // failed
    });
```

Comment: Instead of taking a `callback` parameter, you just should `return` the promise that you produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> should there be another 'then' here or is 'return' ok in order for it to work asynchronously?
>
> ```
> return accountsInDB.updateById(dbAccount._id, {$set: {deleted: true}});
> ```

You can chain another `then` here if you want/need, but that's not important. What is important is that you `return` the promise from the function, so that it can be awaited. If you didn't, the function would still work asynchronous, but out of order - it would just continue immediately after having started the update operation.

> is this return needed?
>
> ```
> else
>    return;
> ```

Nope. It just returns `undefined`, like no `return` would have done as well. You can omit the whole `else` branch.

> WILL THE PROGRAM POTENTIALLY REACH HERE BEFORE `deleted` HAS BEEN SET ON THE REQUIRED ACCOUNTS?
>
> ```
> callback(); // all of the above has finished
> ```

No, it won't. The `map` produces an array of promises, and `q.all` makes a promise that waits for all of them (and fulfills with an array of their results). The `then` will wait for this promise that is returned from its callback before the chain proceeds.

Comment: Cool thanks, so it should be ok to leave as it is then without any tweaks?
Incidentally, I have now added a second return statement:
`return accountsInDB.updateById(dbAccount._id, {$set: {deleted: false}});`

Comment: I would avoid that `callback` thingy, and if at all, it should be `.then(function(res) { callback(null, res); }, function(err) { callback(err); })` [instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572). But other than that it's ok. It's working, right?

Comment: awesome, yes it seems to be working fine, thanks for the tips and clarification :)